# PHP radio buttons returning wrong value

Tags: php, mysql

I have PHP radio buttons being generated by the following code:

```
while($a_row = mysql_fetch_array($answers_result))
    {
        // print each answer choice
        ?>
        <input type='radio' name='question_<?php echo $current_question['id'] ?>'                     
                value='<?php echo $a_row['prompt']?>'><?php echo $a_row['prompt']?>
        <br />

    <?php
    }
```

I am then defining the user's choice with this code:

```
$user_answer = $_POST["question_{$_SESSION['current_question']['id']}"];
```

However, this isn't always returning the value, which should be whatever $a_row['prompt'] is.. If it is the first radio button in the list, it returns "answer 1", etc.. It is not getting the correct values from my sql table. Am I doing something wrong in my code that is causing it to not actually get the "value" of each radio button when the user selects it and submits the form?

Comment: 1. Look in the generated html 2. Look in the sent request (firebug or alternatives) 3. `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: And that code is not returning errors? I am surprised. I see at least 1 syntax error. :/

Comment: care to elaborate on the syntax error(s)?

Comment: is it always returning the same valu. Like if you  have let said 5 Items it only retunr the 1st one?

Comment: Well you forget to escape you '' in the name name='question_<?php echo $current_question[\'id\'] ?>'  also in the Value. that why I prefert to use " "  then in those I use ' ' so they do not interfere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the ' ' as you start with them

```
<input type='radio' name='question_<?php echo $current_question[\'id\']; ?>'                     
            value='<?php echo $a_row[\'prompt\'];?>'><?php echo $a_row['prompt'];?>
```

Also note that your need to finish your PHP command with ; that not the case.

To avoid ' ' trouble I recompend using " " when you know that you will have to add some ' ' in your code, that way they do not interfere.

```
<input type='radio' name="question_<?php echo $current_question['id']; ?>"                     
            value="<?php echo $a_row['prompt'];?>"><?php echo $a_row['prompt'];?>
```